# Debian hybrid graphics, multi monitor nightmare

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

So I have this old POS HP Pavilion dv7 laptop that was collecting dust and I thought why not fool around with Debian and get some linux experience under my belt. It's become a nightmare to say the least.

**What I want:**
-Solid playback of video at 1080p be it on youtube or local files.
-Multi monitor setup via HDMI. Note: HDMI port is part of the HD 5000 series gpu.
-Ability to switch between my systems hybrid graphics setup, there's a integrated Radeon HD 4000 series gpu and a discrete Radeon HD 5000 series gpu.

**What I don't want:**
-Good battery life, this topper of the fat mans lap is the size of my foice x 9000 so it stay's where it is. It will always and forever be plugged into a wall like a tower. I bring this up because I will settle for the HD 5000 running all the time with the integrated gpu disabled.
-Crappy display drivers.

**Details:**
To gain above wants I've come to the conclusion that I need AMD Catalyst. I would just install it but it seems I'm smack dab in the middle of the support gap. AMD Catalyst doesn't support my integrated gpu HD 4000 series but it does support HD 5000. So my question is, can I get the HD 5000 running and the proprietary drivers installed?

Link to doc:
https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary

So far the best I've done is install the free radeon driver for the HD 4000 which works okay but I can't get the wants above. https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo

**Relevant console output/setup details:**
Debian Jessie. I'm using KDE as the ATI proprietary doc states GNOME is not supported. I have no experience with the other desktop environments.

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]

glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa
10.3.2 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30 OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile OpenGL core profile extensions: OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2 OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30 OpenGL context flags: (none) OpenGL extensions: OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2 OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.0 OpenGL ES profile extensions:

sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS-Audio: :Off:0000:02:00.1
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:01:05.0
2:DIS: :DynOff:0000:02:00.0
```

I'm open to trying just about anything to get the listed wants, all the way up to a different debian version. I would like to stay within the debian distro though. A different desktop environment is obviously in play.